# how to select several input values in an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a HTML doc like this

```
<div>
     <span>checkbox 1 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="12" />
     <span>checkbox 2 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="23" />
     <span>checkbox 3 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="38" />
     <span>checkbox 4 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="49" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Make" onclick="do_it()" />
```

I want to have an array which contains values of checked checkbox inputs.

*for example if checkbox 1 and checkbox 3 are checked I need this array = [12,38].*

I have tried several ideas with Javascript and JQuery but I couldn't fix it
:(

Comment: Where are you stuck? Were you not able to select the inputs? If you were, were you not able to filter down to the checked ones? If you were, were you not able to get the values? If you were, were you not able to build an Array?

Comment: it is always better to paste the code whatever you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
       return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative, but not as dry as undefineds:

http://jsfiddle.net/KTR9r/1/

```
<div>
     <span>checkbox 1 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="12" />
     <span>checkbox 2 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="23" />
     <span>checkbox 3 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="38" />
     <span>checkbox 4 : </span><input type="checkbox" value="49" />
</div>
<input id="my_submit" type="submit" value="Make" />

$("#my_submit").click(function() {

    var my_array = [];

    $("input:checkbox" ).each(function() {
        if( $(this).prop('checked') ){
            my_array.push( $(this).val() );
        }
    });    

    console.log(my_array);

});
```